# knockoutjs afterAdd and afterRender problem

Tags: javascript, mvvm, knockout.js

I was working with a simply template, containing an {{each}} block. The whole template would get re-rendered every time something changed in the collection.

I then attached an afterRender event in the template binding. The function called would simply set the focus to the newly added input element. Working perfectly.

```
{{each Fabbricati}}
<li>
    <div style="float: left; clear: left;">
        {{if Editing}}
        <input id="editingitem" type="text" data-bind="value: Name, event: { blur: function() { Editing(false) }, keypress: function(event) { if (event.which == 13) { blur() } return true; } }" />
        {{else}}
        <span data-bind="click: function() { Editing(true) }">${Name() || 'Senza nome'}</span>
        {{/if}}
        - <button class="fancybox edit" data-bind="click: function() { Edit(Id()) }">Modifica</button><button class="remove" data-bind="click: Remove">Rimuovi</button>
    </div>
</li>
{{/each}}
```

and the calling div:

```
<div id="wrapper" data-bind="template: { name: 'navTemplate', afterRender: Prettify </div>
```

Now I tried to move the block inside the {{each}} to a standalone template, and call it using the "foreach" option in the template binding. So far so good, but here's the catch: afterRender won't work anymore. My input won't get the focus.

I already read around the internet that it is intended behaviour, and to use `afterAdd` instead, but this isn't working too. The effects of my `Prettify` function are always added to all elements except the last one added. If I add another one, the previous gets the behaviour, etc.

I'm really stuck. If anyone knows how to fix this, it would be a life saver.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would try taking a look at the new version of knockout in beta at https://github.com/SteveSanderson/knockout/tree/1.3.  It has some different ways of doing the bindings that are simpler and may meet your needs better.  There is a writeup of new features at http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2011/08/31/knockout-1-3-0-beta-available/.

I had some issues similar to what your're having, but used the new control flow bindings as was able to simplify my code a lot.  See below.

With regards to afterRender:

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: products, afterRender: callback">
<li>
    <strong data-bind="text: name"></strong>
    &mdash;
    Last updated: <em data-bind="text: $parent.lastUpdated"></em>
</li>
```

This is similar to code I was running yesterday.  I found that afterRender was called every time a row was generated.  I think this is behavior you're looking for.  Knockout 1.3 Beta Note - afterRender & IE9 have an issue as of today as it will cause an exception.

Comment: make sure your binding is using an ibject for the options like `<ul data-bind="foreach: { data: products, afterRender: callback }">`

Comment: Kris, you saved my day. That had me trumped for a while, wondering why the afterRender wasn't updated.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

From http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/template-binding.html

Using {{each}} with an observable array

When using {{each someArray}}, if your value is an observableArray, ***you must pass the underlying array to each by writing {{each myObservableArray()}}***, not just {{each myObservableArray}}.

So try:

```
{{each Fabbricati()}}
```

Comment: Seems like you didn't read my post at all. I said that with the {{each}} syntax I have no problem at all, all is working fine. My problem is with the template: { foreach: Fabbricati } syntax.

Comment: Okay. Well {{each}} and foreach work differently. {{each}} will rerender the entire template when something changes so afterRender is fired. foreach just removes/adds an individual item and does not rerender the full template so it makes sense afterRender is not called. Have you seen this example: http://knockoutjs.com/examples/animatedTransitions.html ? Maybe you could try the "afterAdd: function(elem) { // do your stuff here } " syntax.

Comment: Again, if you read my whole post, I'm stating that I tried the afterAdd with no success.

Comment: So if you do "afterAdd: function(elem) { // do your stuff here }" what is elem? Is it null or the last element added? (Also could you please refrain from repeatedly saying I haven't read your post - I have. I may have initially missed the gist of it but I am only trying to help here and a little courteousness  would be appreciated. Thanks.)

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't mean to be rude. It's just a bit too much of frustration when working with JS. I'll try to post more details about it as soon as I can. Thanks.